# CSS in WordPress: `100vh` taller than viewport

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using twentytwentyone theme and the image is inside the theme's own "Cover" block.

The block is set to `height: 100vh`, but the image comes out taller than the actual visible space in the viewport. When I scroll it, I can measure the amount of extra height and it's similar to the height of the browser toolbars; maybe that's part of it? Or does WordPress do something funky in the miles of undecipherable CSS?

I did the following in an .html file on my desktop, and in Firefox, the image fits the visible viewport perfectly:

```
<html>
<img src="file:///C:\Users\rickp\OneDrive\Desktop\aurora-australis.jpg" style="height:100vh">
</html>
```

Looks like something I'll have to debug to understand, when I have time to do that. In the meantime, if anyone has encountered this in WordPress, your insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nope, `vh` is a unit based upon the viewport height, and doesn’t include browser chrome (except for, I think, iOS Safari but I can’t verify that). Have you tried to remove padding and margins? Can you reproduce your problem with a simple snippet of css and html?

Comment: <img> is inline by default. The strut that sits on the same line will extend below the image and cause the scrollbar. But not if you don't use a doctype like your example. Wordpress will use a doctype, like any good web page should.

Comment: Sorry, what is a 'strut'?

Comment: A [strut](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#strut) is an "imaginary" inline box that gives each line of text a minimum height.

Comment: There's not enough information to go off to give an actual appropriate answer to your question. There could be a lot of underlying causes. Such as CSS overwrites, overflows etc. etc.. Use the browser dev tools to inspect the element. It should give you some clues.

Comment: @Alohci ahh thanks, wasn't thinking of font terminology in this context. The amount by which it's off is a lot more that, like 3/4 of an inch on a laptop screen.

Comment: @Martin thanks I thought so. I'll debug it when I have time, and maybe ask over at wordpress. It's not a big deal right now, but once I add a "more" icon I'd love to know it's not halfway off the visitor's screen.